# How to restrict relations in an OWL ontology

Tags: data-modeling, owl, ontology, modeling

I have what I think should be a common problem in OWL ontology design, but it proves a bit hard to get direct advice on this.

**Summary:** I need to restrict a ternary relation of 3 taxonomically rich class structures so that the range of the relation is dependent on the respective domain. And I don't absolutely have to model this as schema, I just want to store the information "this subclass is connected to that one" somehow. I see as best options object property restrictions or storing the information as instances, which directly realize the relations I need as instances of a general relation.

**Situation:**

- I have a ternary relation that I modeled by an additional class
- There are two taxonomically rather rich classes `A,B` with respectively many subclasses and a third class `C` with some subclasses that connects to the relationship between subclasses of `A` and `B`
- I introduced class `D` which connects to subclasses of `A,B,C`
- An obfuscated example is: `A` are herbivores, `B` are carnivores and `C` are climatological settings. Now I want to model that certain carnivores hunt certain herbivores and in addition, certain climatological settings affect the hunting behaviour. But not all climatological settings affect all pairs `(a,b)`, so there's interestig information to be stored
- Since I can't point from climatological settings directly to a pair `(a,b)`, I introduce `D`, the class of hunting habits, which relate to carnivores as hunting participants, to herbivores as hunted participants and to climatological settings as modifying setting.

**Problem:**

- I now have a relation from `A` to `D` which is general, yet I don't want every hunting habit (pair of hunting and hunted) to be affected by the same climatological settings
- For example: Maybe I want rain to affect only the hunting habits between macroscopic animals, or I want volcano eruptions to only affect animals that live near volcanoes

**Solution Options:**

- introduce object property restrictions, which are like virtual superclasses (e.g. the class of animals that participate in hunting habits which are affected by volcano eruptions)
- directly introduce all the information in the instance level: create instances of all the animals I want to make assertions about, then also create instances of the climatological settings and hunting habits, then link those instances together
- create a bunch of sub-relations that have domain and range the specific animals, hunting habits and climatological settings

I suspect the answer will be "It depends". In that case, I am really thankful to understand some of the advantages and disadvantages of the options. Of course there might be a really good solution that I am missing.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example ontology of the problem you experience, along with the desired inferences you will like to make?

Comment: Your case seems to be a rather complicated case of ontology engineering. It is not certain that StackOverflow is the right place to find a solution for this. It may require a discussion between a knowledge engineer and an expert of the domain you are trying to model. It may require drawings, examples, arguments, counter arguments, attempts, updated attempts, until you reach an agreement. You may get advises here, but most likely not a definite answer. For these reasons, I tend to believe that your question is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Your question is an interesting challenge, though.